# Nickname field isn't appearing in Admin

Tags: wp-admin, users

I'm getting the following error message when I try to update my user account settings: *Your Nickname must be different than your login name. Please choose a different Nickname.* But there's no Nickname field, so I'm not sure what's happening. I remember that there *used* to be a Nickname field on other sites I've developed

Comment: the error might be related to a plugin? possibly https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29873#comment:1 are you logged in as a

Answer (score 1):

When you display **All Users**, it will display values from *users* table. You will not see Nickname column, because Nickname value is in *usermeta* table. Put the following code to your child theme's `functions.php` file. First filter `manage_users_columns` will add custom column Nickname to **All Users** view. Second filter `manage_users_custom_column` will retrieve values from *usermeta* table for Nickname column.

```
function wpse_add_to_user_table($column) {
    $column['nickname'] = 'Nickname';
    return $column;
}
add_filter('manage_users_columns', 'wpse_add_to_user_table');

function wpse_disply_in_user_table_row($value, $column_name, $user_id) {
    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'nickname' :
            return get_user_meta($user_id, 'nickname', true);
        default:
    }
    return $value;
}
add_filter('manage_users_custom_column', 'wpse_disply_in_user_table_row', 10, 3);
```

Please note that Nickname field is always present when you **Edit** user.